# Finding TopMostWindow/FrontMostWindow in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8

In iOS 7 and earlier, if we want to find topMostWindow in application, we were commonly using following line of code

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject]
```

This will commonly return `UITextEffectsWindow` if there is keyboard available on screen else it returns `UIWindow`.(This is common scenario, not always true)

But, In iOS 8, when i use above command it always gives me `UITextEffectsWindow`. Also, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` always contains 2 objects(`UIWindow` and `UITextEffectWindow`). What should i do to get FrontMostWindow in case of iOS 8.

Answer (score 3):

I think the (internal) `UITextEffectsWindow` is in fact the frontmost window. So I guess the question is not how to get the frontmost window, but what window you want to get.

Maybe you are looking for the key window? (From the docs: "The key window is the one that is designated to receive keyboard and other non-touch related events.")

So this would be

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
```

I think this is the front most window from an end user's perspective (in all cases I have seen so far).

Comment: Just saw https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1813/_index.html -- although the question is a different one, the first answer to it has some good information on windows on iOS that you might find useful to pick the right window.

Comment: I need UITextEffectsWindow when any keyboard or any inputAccessoryView of Textfield is open, else and otherwise i need mainWindow, now, keyWindow never gives us TextEffectsWindow, it always gives mainWindow